# List validation, no duplicates choices

Tags: list, validation

I'm having issues with validation on SP2010. I've created a list with 8 possible shifts my employees can choose and want them to select their most to least preferred shift. I've also set it to they cant see each other's picks. I want to make sure there's no duplicates.

It's my first time using formulas and have been looking online for a better way to do this but haven't found one. To do this, I came up with this formula:

=IF(OR([0700-1500]<>[0800-1600]), if(and([0700-1500]<>[0900-1700]),if(and([0700-1500]<>[1000-1800]), if(and([0700-1500]<>[1100-1900]), if(and([0700-1500]<>[1330-2100]), if(and([0700-1500]<>[1430-2200]), if(and([0700-1500]<>[1530-2300]), 
if(and([0800-1600]<>[0900-1700]),if(and([0800-1600]<>[1000-1800]), if(and([0800-1600]<>[1100-1900]), if(and([0800-1600]<>[1330-2100]), if(and([0800-1600]<>[1430-2200]), if(and([0800-1600]<>[1530-2300]),
if(and([0900-1700]<>[1000-1800]), if(and([0900-1700]<>[1100-1900]), if(and([0900-1700]<>[1330-2100]), if(and([0900-1700]<>[1430-2200]), if(and([0900-1700]<>[1530-2300]), 
if(and([1000-1800]<>[1100-1900]), if(and([1000-1800]<>[1330-2100]), if(and([1000-1800]<>[1430-2200]), if(and([1000-1800]<>[1530-2300]),
if(and([1100-1900]<>[1330-2100]), if(and([1100-1900]<>[1430-2200]), if(and([1100-1900]<>[1530-2300]),
if(and([1330-2100]<>[1430-2200]), if(and([1330-2100]<>[1530-2300]),
if(and([1430-2200]<>[1530-2300]),true,false))

Unfortunately, the formula is too long. is there a way to shorten it?

Also, just to mention, Sharepoint designer has been disabled and cant use jquery.

Any help would be great!
Thanks, Jeff

Comment: its impossible to read the formula, be aware you can only nest 7 levels deep in Formulas. Isn't it easier to reverse your logic and let users select timeslots from Columns: **Shift1** , **Shift2** , **...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To shorten formulas, you need to create calculated columns that represent parts of the formula. After that, you create a formula based on calculated fields. I hope you find it useful.

Comment: cool thanks for the info. Can you tell me what should be in my list validation? I tried =Formula1+[Formula 2] but that didn't work

Comment: Nevermind I got it! You've been a great help!

Comment: I'm glad to read it!